# struts-tags iterator is duplicating rows

Tags: java, hibernate

I am outputting data to an html table using a struts-tags iterator.  It works for the most part but for a few rows, it duplicates the previous row instead of putting in the correct data. Very strange inconsistency.

Here is the html:

```
<s:iterator value="result">
<tr>
<td><s:property value="timestamp"/></td>
<td><s:property value="targetId"/></td>
<td><s:property value="sourceIp"/></td>
<td><s:property value="transactionType"/></td>
<td><s:property value="status"/></td>
</tr>
</s:iterator>
```

"result" is defined in the java controller:

```
private List<AuditData> result
```

and is populated by a hibernate query like so:

```
    session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    Criteria criteria = buildQuery2(session);
    result = criteria.list();
```

Here is an example output of the problem:

```
10/3/16 8:17:31 PM.000  hanogreg    10.10.10.10     Pwd Reset   Success
10/3/16 8:17:31 PM.000  hanogreg    10.10.10.10     Pwd Reset   Success
```

The second row is a duplicate of the first but the database shows the second entry should say "Pwd Change", not "Pwd Reset".

Does anyone have any ideas as to what could be causing this inconsistent behavior?

Edit: This is a hibernate issue, not a struts issue as I can see "result" already contains the duplicate row instead of the real row.  Here is buildQuery2() which creates the hibernate criteria:

```
private Criteria buildQuery2(Session session) throws ParseException {
    Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(AuditData.class);
    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");

    if (!fromDate.equals("All")) {
        Date fDate = df.parse(fromDate);
        criteria.add(Restrictions.ge("timestamp", fDate));
    }
    if (!toDate.equals("All")) {
        Date tDate = df.parse(toDate);
        actionlogger.debug("toDate=" +toDate +", tDate="+tDate.toString());
        tDate = getEndOfDayDate(tDate); //set the time to the last millisecond of the day so all other times will be less
        criteria.add(Restrictions.le("timestamp", tDate));
    }
    if (!csgUsername.equals("All"))     criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("target_id",csgUsername));
    if (!sourceIp.equals("All"))        criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("source_ip",sourceIp));
    if (!transactionType.equals("All")) criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("transaction_type",transactionType));
    if (!status.equals("All"))          criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("status",status));
    criteria.addOrder(Order.asc("timestamp"));

    return criteria;
}
```

Since I was unable to figure out why this was happening, I was forced to re-write the code to do the same thing without hibernate and got it to work correctly.

Comment: Print the `result` in your java code, after `result = criteria.list();`.

Comment: Good suggestion.  I did that and can see that result already contains the duplicated row.  The problem must be in hibernate then.  Any more suggestions?

Comment: What is buildQuery2?

Comment: buildQuery2 is essentially `Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(AuditData.class);`  It just adds some Restrictions based on GUI inputs

Comment: @tekknow You should update your question with your findings. Show your query. Using joins in there, don't you?

Comment: I updated my post with the query.  No joins.